# Keycloak throws an error when retrieving user credentials

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloakjs version 10.0.2 and my keycloak server is of version 10.0.2, I am not able to authorize user in keycloakjs, browser console gets the following error, Please give me some idea on where I am going wrong :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')
at setupCheckLoginIframe (keycloak.js:1219:27)
at processInit (keycloak.js:313:28)
```

Sample code :

```
 <html><head>

<script src="http://localhost:81/auth/js/keycloak.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
const keycloak = Keycloak({
"realm": "test",
"auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
"ssl-required": "external",
"resource": "account",
"public-client": true,
"confidential-port": 0,
"url": 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
"clientId": 'account',
"enable-cors": true
   });
const loadData = () => {
console.log(keycloak.subject);
if (keycloak.idToken) {
    document.location.href = "?user="+keycloak.idTokenParsed.preferred_username;
    console.log('IDToken');
    console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed.preferred_username);
    console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed.email);
    console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed.name);
    console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed.given_name);
    console.log(keycloak.idTokenParsed.family_name);
} else {
    keycloak.loadUserProfile(function() {
        console.log('Account Service');
        console.log(keycloak.profile.username);
        console.log(keycloak.profile.email);
        console.log(keycloak.profile.firstName + ' ' + keycloak.profile.lastName);
        console.log(keycloak.profile.firstName);
        console.log(keycloak.profile.lastName);
    }, function() {
        console.log('Failed to retrieve user details. Please enable claims or account role');
    });
   }
};
const loadFailure =  () => {
 console.log('Failed to load data.  Check console log');
};
const reloadData = () => {
   keycloak.updateToken(10)
        .success(loadData)
             .error(() => {
                console.log('Failed to load data.  User is logged out.');
            });
}
keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(reloadData);
</script>
</head>
 <body>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Please help

Regards
Kris

Answer (score 0):

On modifying the line

```
     keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).success(reloadData);
```

to

```
     keycloakAuth.init({onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false}).success(reloadData);
```

solved this issue